# Angular2 HighCharts Can't Find Module highcharts-3d

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular

I'm trying to integrate the 3d highcharts module to my app, the other chats works fine, but when I add the 3d module, I get on this line a compile error:

```
import Highcharts3d from 'highcharts/highcharts-3d';
```

and the compiler says:

> The module Highcharts3d canno't be found

this is my system js comfig:

I just follow this page configuration:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts

```
  var  map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api', // get latest,
    'angular2-highcharts':        'https://cdn.rawgit.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts/0.1.0/dist', 
    'highcharts/highstock.src':   'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/v4.2.1/highstock.js',
    'highcharts/highcharts-3d':   'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts-dist/v4.2.1/highcharts-3d.src.js',
  };
```

Any ideas of what am I doing whrong?

Answer (score 1):

Insted of that code you should use this lines of code:

```
import { CHART_DIRECTIVES, Highcharts } from 'angular2-highcharts';

System.import('highcharts/highcharts-3d').then((Highcharts3d) => {
      Highcharts3d(Highcharts);
});
```

Best regards

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!